# ADB Swipe mac/Linux invalid "Error: Invalid arguments for command: swipe"

Tags: shell-script

Boas,
Eu utilizei um script que corre todos os comandos de um ficheiro txt e só obtenho o erro "Error: Invalid arguments for command: swipe" quando corro com o script os adb shell input funcionam todos.

Sei que não é do comando pois se o copiar e cola-lo no terminal ele funciona normalmente.

código do ficheiro sh:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ficheiro commands:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro:
[image: Esse comando se o copiar para o terminal e der enter funciona direito]

Já estou a alguns dias a tentar ver o que poderá ser mas sem sucesso.

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.